# How to prevent infants from rolling out of bed?

Tags: infant, behavior, sleep, bedroom

My seven months old daughter is rolling quite a lot nowadays. This is cute when she is awake and we are present.

However, lately she is also rolling in her bed during the night, when she awakes for a while. This is a bit problematic, because we have a Montessori-bed: the mattress is in the floor without any fence whatsoever. This means that when she reaches the edge of the mattress, she falls. Having the matress in the floor means that the fall is very small, so she just lands in the little tatami the mattress lies on. However, this also means that she does not have the blanket over her anymore and may get cold.

In general, she sometimes cries a little bit, but in most of the cases she just falls asleep again and we find her sleeping in a funny prawn position next to the mattress.

We have tried fixing the blanket around her, so it is more complicated for her to get out of it. However, she ends up being able to do so.

Do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Would it be possible to install a barrier that will keep her from rolling out, but NOT prevent her from CLIMBING out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One common suggestion is [a pool noodle](https://ne.reddit.com/r/LifeProTips/comments/vksy3/kids_fall_out_of_bed_1_fitted_sheet_1_pool_noodle/) under the edge of the mattress sheet. It will not prevent a very aggressive or active roller from escaping and can still be climbed over at will, but if she's just tossing and turning it should keep her on the mattress.

[image: pool noodle under sheet]

Comment: Good answer! I was going to suggest the same thing, which I used with my middle child who had a hard time adjusting to a bed. He was, and still is, a crazy sleeper who fell out of bed a lot. A rolled up (lengthwise) beach towel works too.

Comment: This is a suffocation risk. Any barrier should be porous and breathable, as it's very common for the child to end up with their face pressed up against it.

Comment: When the sheet is stretched over, it makes a slope rather than a distinct edge.

Comment: @Erica Yes I understand now. Sorry, I didn't check the picture carefully enough.

Comment: It's always OK to be careful, and it is certainly a good reminder to any parent to be thoughtful and consider all possible risks when implementing a solution :) (Sticking a pool noodle on top of the sheets, for example, would be a less good idea...)

Comment: @Erica This could double as a lifehack!

Answer (score 5):

We had the same issue with our daughter and we had to improvise. The Bedrail is designed to use with a bed however it works perfectly with a mattress only.

[image]

It's a stretchy net so even if the baby pushes hard it'll push him/her back gently. The frame is made of very light plastic parts so even if it falls on the baby for any reason it won't her him/her

Keep in mind that I still think Erica's solution is way SAFER. My answer is only from personal experience that I should share to make the question more informative.

Comment: This is safer than a pool noodle, because that inner bit is breathable mesh. These things are designed to be used for this exact purpose. Pool noodles are not.

Comment: @user1751825 thanks for the info! You are right it's a mesh, now I know why

Answer (score 3):

Since you have described the rolling out of bed as harmless, your real question seems to be about how to prevent your child from getting cold (and waking up) due to having lost their blanket.

Until they are old enough to solve the lost blanket situation without help, you can use an [infant sleeping bag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_bag#Infant_use) for your child.  Such a garment is considerably harder for your child to remove by itself, ensuring that it does not happen accidentally.

[Apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudden_infant_death_syndrome#Sleep_sacks) they have some other benefits as well.